# Get index of rows with not equal values across several columns, excluding NA

Tags: r, dplyr

Using as an example this data frame:

```
a   b   c   d   e

1   x   x   A   x
2   y   y   A   NA
3   z   v   B   NA
4   x   w   T   w
5   s   NA  K   NA
```

How could I get as TRUE those rows where values across `b`, `c` and `e` columns are not equal, excluding NAs. The idea is to get TRUE (or the index) for the following rows:

```
a   b   c   d   e

3   z   v   B   NA
4   x   w   T   w
```

So, my intention is to get those rows where `b`, `c` and `e` are not equal. But in case some of this rows is NA but the other are equal, this should not count as not equal, as NAs should be ignored.

I was trying something like:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  filter(if_all(c(c,e), ~ b == .b))
```

But this way I get TRUE for equal values and, in addition, I get problems with NA.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: just to clarify- you are looking for the rows where b, c, and e are not all the same value - you don't care if, say, c and e are the same value but b is different?

Comment: If c and e are the same but b is different, then I would also want to get that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply(
  df[, c("b", "c", "e")],
  1,
  function(row) {
    row <- row[!is.na(row)]
    any(row != row[1])
  }
)

#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Where `df` is:

```
df <- read.table(text =
'a   b   c   d   e

1   x   x   A   x
2   y   y   A   NA
3   z   v   B   NA
4   x   w   T   w
5   s   NA  K   NA', 
  header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP wants to output TRUE for rows in which all values are unique, exluding NAs. We can use `table` rowwise and output TRUE if `all` values of the table are `1`(no duplicates).
Remember to `pick`the desired columns to feed the function.
Filtering on this new index variable is straightforward.

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:4),
    a = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'z'),
    b = c('b', 'b', 'c', 'a'),
    c = c('c', 'b', NA, 'd'))

library(dplyr)

df |> 
    mutate(index = apply(pick(a:c), 1, table) |> 
               lapply(\(x) all(x ==1)
                      )
           )

  a b    c index
1 a b    c  TRUE
2 a b    b FALSE
3 a c <NA>  TRUE
4 z a    d  TRUE
```

A modified, simpler version, with `purrr::pmap`:

```
df |> 
    mutate(index = pmap(pick(a:c), \(...) all(table(c(...)) == 1)))

  id a b    c index
1  1 a b    c  TRUE
2  2 a b    b FALSE
3  3 a c <NA>  TRUE
4  4 z a    d  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I don't understand it. I was expecting the index to be:  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE. I would like to get those rows where b,c and e are not equal, in a way that having NA in some of those variables does not count as unequality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     filter(sum(!is.na(c_across(c('b', 'c', 'e')))) > 1, length(unique(na.omit(c_across(c('b', 'c', 'e'))))) > 1) %>%
     ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 5
      a b     c     d     e    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     3 z     v     B     NA   
2     4 x     w     T     w
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an elegant way to get, instead of the subset, simply the index of the rows accomplishing the condition or a logical vector?

Comment: you could simply select the ```a``` column